# What is way to render *%{color:orange}Hello !!%* in textview or webview in android

Tags: android

What is way to render *%{color:orange}Hello !!%* in textview or webview in android?

For example Gmail render this as follows:
`*%{color:orange}Hello !!%*` should rendered in android textview/webview as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfibE.jpg)

Same is working in web page but i am wondering to render it in android textview/webview

Answer (score 0):

In your layout XML, try adding these codes:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_text_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello !!"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#FA8F20"/> <!-- This is the color you want -->
```

Comment: This will be hardcoded m looking for something which will render in place like Html.fromHtml()

Answer (score 0):

Try to format it using `Html.fromHtml` and set it to `TextView`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#FFA500>Hello !!</font>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#FFA500>Hello !!</font>");
}
```

Comment: This will work..but i have got lot of data marked up like `*%{color:orange}Hello !!%*`,so it will be unfair to parse every tags and write code accordingly. I m looking if any preprocessor kind of thing like Html.fromHtml() to do this for me